# rviz setViewController doesn't hook up mouse events?

Tags: ros, librviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an librviz application https://github.com/lucasw/visualization_tutorials/tree/set-view-controller-test which works fine with the default view controller, but I would like to use a different controller.
It seems like this should be done with setViewController(), it renders the view from a default zero starting point but the mouse doesn't rotate or translate the view.

This is in my constructor:

```
  ...
  manager_->initialize();
  manager_->startUpdate();

  rviz::ViewController* view = new rviz::OrbitViewController();
  if (view)
  {
    view->initialize(manager_);
    render_panel_->setViewController(view);
  }
```

Is something missing that will cause the view controller handleMouseEvents() to get called?
Some additional comments are here:

https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/997

And a visualization_tutorial issue here https://github.com/ros-visualization/visualization_tutorials/issues/36

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256100/rviz-setviewcontroller-doesn%27t-hook-up-mouse-events?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2017-03-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2017-03-05**:
Is this a straight-up `rviz` or `rqt` plugin? I ask 'cuz your link is to a `librviz` question and my experience with `rqt` is minimal. Can you post more information (and code/links) to better describe your situation?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-03-06**:
It is an rqt plugin that uses librviz.  Do you have any code that uses `setViewController`?  I can try to duplicate the problem with `visualization_tutorials/librviz_tutorial` independent of rqt.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-03-06**:
I've added a link to a setViewController version of librviz_tutorial and rqt is no longer part of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution is to use view manager setCurrentViewControllerType

```
  manager_ = new rviz::VisualizationManager( render_panel_ );
  render_panel_->initialize( manager_->getSceneManager(), manager_ );
  manager_->initialize();
  manager_->startUpdate();

  QString class_id = "rviz/Orbit";
  manager_->getViewManager()->setCurrentViewControllerType(class_id);
```

Using `setViewController` leaves the view manager still holding on to the default view controller which gets updated, but is no longer getting rendered.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0